# Django connection to PostgreSQL: "Peer authentication failed"

Tags: django, postgresql

```
OperationalError at /admin/

FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

This is the error I am receiving when I try to get to my Django admin site. I had been using MySQL database no problem. I am new to PostgreSQL, but decided to switch because the host I ultimately plan to use for this project does not have MySQL.

Therefore, I figured I could go through the process of installing PostgreSQL, run a `syncdb` and be all set.

Problem is that I cannot seem to get my app to connect to the database. I can login to PostgreSQL via command line or desktop app that I downloaded. Just not in the script.

Also, I can use `manage.py shell` to access the db just fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

I took a peek at the exception, noticed it had to do with my connection settings. Went back to **settings.py**, and saw I did not have a Host setup. Add `localhost` and voila.

My settings.py did not have a HOST for MySQL database, but I needed to add one for PostgreSQL to work.

In my case, I added `localhost` to the `HOST` setting and it worked.

Here is the `DATABASES` section from my `settings.py`.

```py
DATABASES = { 
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<MYDATABASE>', 
        'USER': '<MYUSER>', 
        'PASSWORD': '<MYPASSWORD>', 
        'HOST': 'localhost', # the missing piece of the puzzle 
        'PORT': '', # optional, I don't need this since I'm using the standard port
    } 
}
```

Comment: you might consider moving the solution from your question to your answer (and accepting it). In this way, the question will remain a question and it will have properly provided answer. BTW: good job! :-)

Comment: Stumbled across the same issue with Rails 3 and your suggestion fixed the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Had the same problem with a Rails app, and it was the same solution - the host needed to be configured in `config/database.yml` - that is to say, in that file I needed to add the line `host: localhost` (or wherever you postgres server is - mine was local)

Comment: When the HOST is blank, Django attempts to connect to the database using UNIX sockets.  On the other hand, when the HOST is "localhost", it connects via TCP/IP to 127.0.0.1.  Likely, your `pg_hba.conf` is set up to deny ordinary users from connecting through UNIX sockets but allows them over TCP/IP from localhost.

Comment: Documentation ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#host ) lies: "HOST [...] An empty string means localhost". This is not true, I had the same problem and I fixed it writing 'localhost'. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Ah HA! I knew I KNEW the password. Mezzanine produces a `local_settings.py` file and the `# Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.` is in their. LIES!!!

Answer (score 31):

That is probably because your script is running under some other user than the one you are trying to connect with (*myuser* here). In this case, peer authentication will fail. Your solution with `HOST: "localhost"` works because you are not using peer auth anymore. However, it is slower than `HOST: ""` because instead of using unix sockets, you use TCP connections. From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/):

> If you’re using PostgreSQL, by default (empty HOST), the connection to
>   the database is done through UNIX domain sockets (‘local’ lines in
>   pg_hba.conf). If you want to connect through TCP sockets, set HOST to
>   ‘localhost’ or ‘127.0.0.1’ (‘host’ lines in pg_hba.conf). On Windows,
>   you should always define HOST, as UNIX domain sockets are not
>   available.

If you want to keep using sockets, correct settings in `pg_hba.conf` are needed. The most simple is:

```
local   all         all                               trust
```

while commenting out all other `local` lines in the config. Note that reloading postgres is needed for this change to take effect.

But if multi-user production machine is in question, you might want to use something more secure like `md5` (see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-methods.html) for explanation of various authentication methods).

Answer (score 15):

Better than fully trust is just to set it to md5.

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                           md5
```

Comment: +1; but note md5 is in general (slightly) better than password as it will send a hash as opposed to a password.  (When local it doesn't matter much; but if doing it over the network with possible eavesdroppers it is significant.)

Comment: If PostgreSQL doesn't salt password hashes - and I don't know if it does or not - then anyone sophisticated enough to actually eavesdrop on your connection is probably going to run your hash through a rainbow table and break your security anyhow.

Comment: "md5" is better than "trust", but the best is to use "peer" and create a Linux user without login permissions, for local connections only. This way you have to provide your root password to access the db from local.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this by editing the bottom of /etc/postgres/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf to be (changing md5 to trust; NOTE this means there will be no database password, which may not be what you want)

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled upon the same problem but wanted to use unix sockets as clime said, but by still using the `peer` method. I mapped my system-username with the postgres-username inside the `pg_hba.conf`, which is working with the `peer` method.

Inside `pg_hba.conf` i added:

```
local all all peer map=map-name
```

Inside `pg_ident.conf` i added:

```
map-name mysystem-username mypostgres-username
```